# What is the origin of the expression "close, but no cigar"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

It's a bizarre expression that I've always taken to describe a situation in which one has very nearly achieved their objective. Where do the roots of this expression lie?

Comment: There's a flood of hits for "origin of close but no cigar" - the majority attribute the expression to a carnival barker's exclamation when somebody came close to ringing the bell with the hammer in the game testing one's strength.  A cigar was apparently a common prize for ringing the bell.

Comment: With reference to the downvotes, I'm new to this SE site. Is this kind of question not a good fit for the site?

Comment: Hum, I guess I'm not used to this domain then. I thought showing what I think it means was sufficient. Oh well..

Comment: Sorry, Zaid, I tried to add some links for useful sites to do a preliminary research on your own but the comment box kept timing out on me (I'm on my phone today).  The EL&U FAQs are helpful too.  I appreciate your perserverence!  Please stick around!

Comment: Googling `origin of close but no cigar` returned [this](http://www.knowyourphrase.com/phrase-meanings/Close-But-No-Cigar.html), [this](http://voices.yahoo.com/origins-phrase-close-but-no-cigar-6041944.html), and [this](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/close-but-no-cigar.html) among the top hits, which might make folks wonder why you needed to ask here. If you weren't so lucky with your first Google query, then you could at least mention what you tried in your unsuccessful attempts to find an answer.

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. Please edit your question to include context (why you are asking, or the example text you are trying to understand), and to include the results of research you did before asking here. The lack of this information probably explains the downvotes. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A cigar, as a luxury, is often awarded and smoked to celebrate a success, in much the same way that champagne is drunk.

The earliest quotation in the OED is from the *Cleveland* (Ohio) *Plain Dealer* of **March 6th, 1930**:

> [Bowling] Peters..toppled the maples for 120, 100 and 100. Scott was right behind him with 113, 115 and 117. Close—but no cigar.

I found a slight antedating in the *[Princeton Alumni Weekly](http://books.google.fi/books?id=QBJbAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA1166&dq=%22close%20but%20no%20cigar%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sXAqUZP4Bubi4QS1zIDADQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22close%20but%20no%20cigar%22&f=false)* (Volume XXIX, No. 36 - Page 1166) of **July 2, 1929**:

> The long distance trophy, an appropriately inscribed silver cigarette case, was awarded to Em Gooch who had made the trip from Lincoln, Neb. for the occasion. Several other members came **close, but no cigar,** and we trust that all those in New York and Philadelphia who failed to show up, without reason, will read these lines with a quiver.

Barry Popik's [The Big Apple](http://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/close_but_no_cigar/) includes a brief history of awarded cigars:

> A cigar was traditionally one of the rewards at carnivals for winning at games of skill or chance. Coney Island offered many such games in the early 1900s. Most people did not win a prize; for them, the carnival barker would declare: “Close, but no cigar!”
>
> “Close, but no cigar!” is cited in print from at least 1929, but the cigar-prize existed since at least the early 1900s.

A slightly earlier citation is given, from the *Long Island Daily Press* (Jamaica, NY) of **18 May 1929**, as a headline:

> **Close; But No Cigar**
>
> If you are one of those folks who keep a scrap-book of unimportant but nevertheless not altogether uninteresting facts, you might jot down this one brought in by a dirtgetter in Springfield Gardens. It’s about Hugo Straub. Hugo is believed to have set a world’s record in the business of getting-defeated-for-the-presidency. Hugo has finished second in no less than two presidential races within one week.